# QImage Rotation without losing infomation

Tags: qt, qimage

I have a QImage of size 12x12 in GIF format. I want to rotate it on certain angle with very high frequency. My application involves a robot so when it changes its orientation(which it does very frequently) my QImage in simulation should also be rotated but it causes loss of information. I am doing it something like below.

```
 robot_transform.rotate(angle);
*robot2 = robot->transformed(robot_transform,Qt::SmoothTransformation);
*robot2=  robot2->scaled(12,12, Qt::KeepAspectRatio,Qt::SmoothTransformation);
```

I need suggestions that whats wrong in this approach and secondly is there any other optimal approach for the desired application?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would increase the resolution of the source image to at least double. Rotating an image to non-90-degree angles will cause loss of pixel information. An higher res source can compensate for that.

Most sprite based animations use pre-rendered images for each possible angle.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the scaling afterwards, you need to crop the center of the image. You can do this with [QImage::copy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#copy).